# Mocking of private methods using PowerMockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermockito

I am trying to mock a private method using PowerMockito.

Sample code is given below.

Ideally *m2()* should be returning "from spy method".

Not sure what could be missing.

Please clarify.

**Sample.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Sample {

    public void m1(String input) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Sample.m1() BEGIN");
        String r = m2(input);
        System.out.println("Sample.m1() END--> " + r);
    }

    private String m2(String s) {
        System.out.println("Sample.m2()" + s);
        return "From m2 method";
    }

}
```

**SampleTest.java**

```
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ Sample.class })
public class SampleTest {

    @Test
    public void testM1() throws Exception {
        Sample spy = PowerMockito.spy(new Sample());
        PowerMockito.doReturn("from spy method").when(spy, "m2", anyString());

        Sample sample = new Sample();
        sample.m1("Hi m1!!!");
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Sample.m1() BEGIN
Sample.m2()Hi m1!!!
Sample.m1() END--> From m2 method
```

Comment: I don't know about PowerMockito but searching for an example, like [this one](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/powermockito/powermockito-spy-example/), shows that you should do `spy.m1("Hi m1!!!")` and not create a new instance...

Comment: So, you have some code that you can't mock, which has side effects you can't easily observe (you need to capture System.out somehow)? Can I suggest you might want to think about redesigning your code for testability.

Comment: @AndyTurner Totally agree. Unfortunately, I am working on a legacy code and refactoring is not an option at this point of time. The code I posted is a sample one to demonstrate the issue. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to call m1() on spy instance instead of sample instance.
Thanks to [Giacomo Alzetta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8718773/giacomo-alzetta) for the suggestion.

Modified code:

```
@Test
    public void testM1() throws Exception {
        Sample spy = PowerMockito.spy(new Sample());
        PowerMockito.doReturn("from spy method").when(spy, "m2", anyString());

        spy.m1("Hi m1!!!");
    }
```